# Visual Studio Code installation with WSL 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have WSL 2 installed and running well and I am trying to install VSC to debug my code.
I already use (and have installed) Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

The first thing I did was to install the .deb package provided on VSC (`sudo apt install ./code_1.46.1-1592428892_amd64.deb`. Everything went fine. When running `code .` I was prompted with

> To use VS Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install VS Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the 'Visual Studio Code' command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.

I proceeded to uninstall VSC from my Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get purge code` and now I am a bit stuck.
On Windows side I installed the `Remote - WSL extension` and `Remote Development` on the existing VSC installation, but now I cannot launch it from WSL.

Any workaround?

**Later edit** : I know it might sound dumb, but it works by just closing all instances of WSL bash and starting all over again. Now I just have the curiosity of what did I install and what did I uninstall? And why is this non persistant?

Answer (score 2):

when you run code . from inside WSL it should install a small vs code server in your home directory (~/.vscode-server) and then lunch vs code. If that doesn't work post the error message.

Comment: Well, I believe that WSL2 should somehow "know" of my VS code server and app on the Windows side, right?

Comment: It should, there's a possibility that it got confused with the vs code you had on Ubuntu.

Comment: So if I don't want vs code server on my wsl, what I have to do is just remove ~/.vscode-server?